# regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, expression

I'm trying to get it so that the alert message pops up if the value entered into the textBox is not a decimal number between 0.0 and 4.9 with just one digit before and after the decimal, but the message pops up regardless of what number I entered and I think there's something wrong with my regular expression but I can't figure it out.

```
if ((textBox.value.search("/^[0-4]\\.[0-9]$/")) == -1) {
    alert("Invalid Entry");
    return false;
}
```

The return false is there since if the number is invalid then the function will exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
if ((textBox.value.match(/^[0-4]\.[0-9]$/))) {
    alert("Invalid Entry");
    return false;
}
```

Here you aren't interested in the position of match but only in the fact of matching so it isn't necessary to use `search`, `match` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this without using a RegExp, by parsing the value to number via [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) and checking the result via [isFinite](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite).

```
// Parse the value as a float. If the value cannot be parsed,
// `parseFloat` will return NaN    
var toFloat = parseFloat( textBox.value );

// Use `isFinite` to verify that parsing was successful. If it
// was, just check the range (i.e. between 0 and 4.9)
if ( isFinite( toFloat ) && toFloat >= 0 && toFloat <= 4.9 ) {
    // Input is valid
} else {
    // Input is invalid
}
```

hope that helps. cheers!